# How can I dispose System.Xml.XmlWriter in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dispose, idisposable

I am trying to dispose XmlWriter object:

```
try
{
    [System.Xml.XmlWriter] $writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create('c:\some.xml')
}
finally
{
    $writer.Dispose()
}
```

Error:

> Method invocation failed because
>   [System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter]
>   doesn't contain a method named
>   'Dispose'.

On the other side:

```
 $writer -is [IDisposable]
 # True
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dispose is [protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.dispose(loband).aspx) on `System.Xml.XmlWriter`.  You should use `Close` instead.

```
$writer.Close
```

Comment: Having a protected method, how can I call it in PowerShell? Type cast does not work '($writer -as [IDisposable]).Dispose()'. Should I use .Net Reflection API??

Comment: Call Close instead of Dispose.  Close releases all resources.

Comment: You're talking about the "wrong" `Dispose`. The [`Dispose` he wants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357166.aspx) is not `protected`; it is an explicit interface implementation! Explicit interface implementations are hard to call from PowerShell. But this *hack* should work: `[IDisposable].GetMethod("Dispose").Invoke($writer, @())`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an alternative approach:

```
(get-interface $obj ([IDisposable])).Dispose()
```

Get-Interface script can be found here http://www.nivot.org/2009/03/28/PowerShell20CTP3ModulesInPracticeClosures.aspx and was suggested in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746014/how-can-i-call-explicitly-implemented-interface-method-from-powershell/761338#761338).

With 'using' keyword we get:

```
$MY_DIR = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent

# http://www.nivot.org/2009/03/28/PowerShell20CTP3ModulesInPracticeClosures.aspx
. ($MY_DIR + '\get-interface.ps1')

# A bit modified code from http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2009/03/12/reserving-keywords.aspx
function using
{
    param($obj, [scriptblock]$sb)

    try {
        & $sb
    } finally {
        if ($obj -is [IDisposable]) {
            (get-interface $obj ([IDisposable])).Dispose()
        }
    }
}

# Demo
using($writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create('c:\some.xml')) {

}
```

Comment: using 'using' in powershell 2.0 i get: The 'using' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
At line:1 char:6
+ using <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReservedKeywordNotAllowed

Comment: Do you mean that the sample is not working on 2.0. Or it's your own code fails - if so, notice that I had to defined the 'using' keyword in sample above by myself.