# How can I call explicitly implemented interface method from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, casting, explicit-interface

Code:

```
add-type @"
    public interface IFoo
    {
        void Foo();
    }

    public class Bar : IFoo
    {
        void IFoo.Foo()
        {
        }
    }
"@ -Language Csharp

$bar = New-Object Bar
($bar -as [IFoo]).Foo() # ERROR.
```

Error:

> Method invocation failed because [Bar]
>   doesn't contain a method named 'Foo'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news: It's a bug.

https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=249840&SiteID=99

Comment: I have Microsoft Live account, but still can't open the link: Page Not Found. :-(

Comment: More info:  http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/169391-access-interfaces-members-net-object.html

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like

```
$bar = New-Object Bar
[IFoo].GetMethod("Foo").Invoke($bar, @())
```

You get (the *reflection* representaion of) the member of `IFoo` from the `Type` object and call an [`Invoke` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx). Too bad one has to do it that way, though.
Similar approach for explicitly implemented properties etc.

If the method takes arguments, they go in the array `@()` after the comma in the code above, of course.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote something for PowerShell v2.0 that makes it easy to call explicit interfaces in a natural fashion:

```
PS> $foo = get-interface $bar ([ifoo])
PS> $foo.Foo()
```

See:

http://www.nivot.org/2009/03/28/PowerShell20CTP3ModulesInPracticeClosures.aspx (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170707062517/http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2009/03/28/PowerShell20CTP3ModulesInPracticeClosures)).

It does this by generating a dynamic module that thunks calls to the interface. The solution is in pure powershell script (no nasty add-type tricks).

-Oisin

Comment: Thank you, Oisin! I added an answer based on your solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/745956/how-can-i-dispose-system-xml-xmlwriter-in-powershell/767661#767661