# How to instruct PowerShell to garbage collect .NET objects like XmlSchemaSet?

Tags: powershell, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, xsd, xmlschemaset

I created a PowerShell script which loops over a large number of XML Schema (.xsd) files, and for each creates a .NET [`XmlSchemaSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.aspx) object, calls [`Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecy9csyh.aspx) and [`Compile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset.compile.aspx) to add a schema to it, and prints out all validation errors.

This script works correctly, but there is a memory leak somewhere, causing it to consume gigabytes of memory if run on 100s of files.

What I essentially do in a loop is the following:

```
$schemaSet = new-object -typename System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet
register-objectevent $schemaSet ValidationEventHandler -Action {
    ...write-host the event details...
}
$reader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($schemaFileName)
[void] $schemaSet.Add($null_for_dotnet_string, $reader)
$reader.Close()
$schemaSet.Compile()
```

(A full script to reproduce this problem can be found in this gist: https://gist.github.com/3002649.  Just run it, and watch the memory usage increase in Task Manager or Process Explorer.)

Inspired by some blog posts, I tried adding

```
remove-variable reader, schemaSet
```

I also tried picking up the `$schema` from `Add()` and doing

```
[void] $schemaSet.RemoveRecursive($schema)
```

These seem to have some effect, but still there is a leak.  I'm presuming that older instances of `XmlSchemaSet` are still using memory without being garbage collected.

**The question:** How do I properly teach the garbage collector that it can reclaim all memory used in the code above?  Or more generally: how can I achieve my goal with a bounded amount of memory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft has confirmed that this is a bug in PowerShell 2.0, and they state that this has been resolved in PowerShell 3.0.

The problem is that an event handler registered using Register-ObjectEvent is not garbage collected.  In reponse to a support call, Microsoft said that

> "we’re dealing with a bug in PowerShell v.2. The issue is caused
>   actually by the fact that the .NET object instances are no longer
>   released due to the event handlers not being released themselves. The
>   issue is no longer reproducible with PowerShell v.3".

The best solution, as far as I can see, is to interface between PowerShell and .NET at a different level: do the validation completely in C# code (embedded in the PowerShell script), and just pass back a list of `ValidationEventArgs` objects.  See the fixed reproduction script at https://gist.github.com/3697081: that script is functionally correct and leaks no memory.

(Thanks to Microsoft Support for helping me find this solution.)

---

Initially Microsoft offered another workaround, which is to use `$xyzzy = Register-ObjectEvent -SourceIdentifier XYZZY`, and then at the end do the following:

```
Unregister-Event XYZZY
Remove-Job $xyzzy -Force
```

**However**, this workaround is functionally incorrect.  Any events that are still 'in flight' are lost at the time these two additional statements are executed.  In my case, that means that I miss validation errors, so the output of my script is incomplete.

Answer (score 4):

After the `remove-variable` you can try to force GC collection :

```
[GC]::Collect()
```

Comment: That does make the increase less, so this may help in practice; but the amount of memory used is still gradually increasing.

Comment: As described in [another StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/745965/223837) this is not directly possible in PowerShell, and it is not necessary because `Close()` implies a `Dispose()` as per recommended Microsoft convention.

Comment: @MarnixKlooster I use a powershell.exe.config to load .net 4.0 framework and I can do $reader.dispose(). Sorry for bad information.

Comment: No problem-- could you please put a brief description how exactly you "use a powershell.exe.config to load .NET 4.0 framework" as an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/745956/223837?  Thanks!

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime